# Number Theory - Primitive roots

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be positive integer.
$G$ is cyclic and finite group generated by $g$.
I need to prove that for every positive integer $k$ :

$$O(g^k) = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$$

I don't really know what to do here. I know that if $G$ generated by $g$ so for $g^k$, $\gcd(k,n)=1$ and from the order there is $x$ so $o((g^k)^x)=1_G$ but what can I do from here??

Comment: I changed \operatorname{gcd} to \gcd.  (This doesn't work with \lcm though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to do. You need to show that (i) $g^k$ raised to the power $n/\gcd(n,k)$ is the identity and (ii) nothing cheaper will work.

Doing (i) is a calculation. Let $n=n_1 d$ and $k=k_1 d$.

For (ii), suppose that $(g^k)^i$ is the identity. Then $n$ divides $ki$, and therefore $n_1$ divides $k_1 i$. Conclude from this that $k$ divides $i$, and you are close to the end.

Comment: why do I have a hint to use the congruence kx=0 mod n?

Comment: I have the same "hint" as part of the solution! Fourth paragraph, "Then $n$ divides $ki$". You can out that in congruence notation $ki\equiv 0\pmod{n}$. Then if using congruence notation continue with $\frac{k}{d}\equiv 0 \pmod{\frac{n}{d}}$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more general setting:

> Let $G$ be a group, and $a\in G$ be an element of finite order, say $|a|=m$. Then for every $n$, we have that $$|a^n|=\frac{m}{(m,n)}$$

Intuitively, you can think the following: $m$ is the least positive integer for which $a^m=e$. It might be very well the case that $n$ shares factors with $m$. In that case, $a^n$ is will need less factors of $m$ to get to $e$. The $(m,n)$ part is simply taking out those common factors, and saying all that needs to be done is add the missing ones, which are in $m/(m,n)$. Now, the proof can go as follows:

**P** We have that

$$nk\equiv 0\mod m\iff  \frac{nk}{(m,n)}\equiv 0\mod \frac{m}{(m,n)} $$

We have that $a^{nk}=e$ if and only if $nk=0\mod m$. Thus, consider the set $$A=\{k\in\Bbb Z:nk\equiv 0\mod m\}$$

By the above, it is equal to the set

$$A'=\left\{k\in\Bbb Z:\frac{m}{(m,n)}\mid \frac{n}{(m,n)}k\right\}$$

But since $\frac{m}{(m,n)}$ and $\frac{n}{(m,n)}$ are coprime, this is the same set as

$$A''=\left\{k\in\Bbb Z:\frac{m}{(m,n)}\mid  k\right\}=\left\{k\frac{m}{(m,n)}:k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$$

The order of $a^n$ will be the least positive integer in $A=A'=A''$. It is immediate this is $\frac{m}{(m,n)}$